# Camera rotation unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i got a fnaf-like 3d unity project and i want to make a camera rotation by pressing a and d buttons but only result that i got was just changing rotation position

i was trying to make the rotation slower but it wasn't any result. i was using this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameramov : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float camerapos = transform.rotation.y;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            while (this.gameObject.transform.rotation.y < camerapos + 90) 
            {
                 camerapos += 1;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            while (this.gameObject.transform.rotation.y < camerapos - 90)
            {
                camerapos -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update is called every frame. So Time.deltaTime needs to be somewhere. The while statement is misused here, it will never update visually anything, only the end-result after the `while`. To create a smooth animation it needs to be done over several frames and so several calls to `Update`. This is the most basic stuff you can find at Unity3D learning pages and millions of millions tutorials everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what behavior you're going for, but I can comment on a number of things right away:

1. `transform.rotation.y` is not what you think it is. `transform.rotation` is a [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html). Quaternions are complicated and you do not want to read or modify them directly. What you want is `transform.eulerAngles`.
2. Nowhere are you applying the rotation to anything. You're modifying camerapos but not assigning anything to use it.
3. Those while loops seem wrong. The one for "a" is an infinite loop I believe. The one for "d" could be made constant time if you replace it with:

```cs
if(this.gameObject.transform.rotation.y < camerapos - 90)
{
    camerapos = this.gameObject.transform.rotation.y + 90;
}
```

But you probably don't want to use this either, because I have a feeling you are trying to achieve something different from what this code does. So if you explain more precisely what behavior you want your camera to have, I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: thanks, but when i am trying to create a "camerapos" i get an error " Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context" maybe didn't understand right this is what i am trying to do:
    public class cameramov : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private float camerapos = this.gameObject.transform.rotation.y;
So i just want to do smooth cam rotation

Comment: @kavunqwe, think we all can assume what behaviour you want. But on SO we're a bit sensitive about asking questions. Please read (and apply) [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @kavunqwe You can't just create a variable called "camerapos" and expect Unity to understand what you mean for it to do. You need to assign the camera position in the place that the Unity API has designated for that purpose. In this case, that's the transform, so you'll want to [consult the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) on transform functions.
My recommendation is that you go to YouTube and look up a Unity tutorial for beginners, and also a C# tutorial before going any further.